# Cumulative sum just repeats the col I want it to sum

Tags: r, cumsum

I have this data frame and I have calculated the cumulative count for `ID` for each `Date`, which is  `cumcount`

```
df<-
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18632, 18632, 18632, 18632, 
18632, 18632, 18632, 18632, 18632, 18632, 18633, 18633, 18633, 
18633, 18633, 18633, 18633, 18642, 18642, 18642, 18642, 18642, 
18642, 18642, 18642, 18642, 18642, 18642, 18642, 18642, 18642, 
18642, 18642, 18642, 18649, 18649, 18649, 18649, 18649, 18649, 
18649, 18649, 18649, 18649, 18649, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 
18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 
18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 
18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 18654, 
18655, 18655, 18655, 18655, 18655, 18655, 18655, 18655, 18655, 
18655, 18655, 18655, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 
18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 
18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18656, 18661, 
18661, 18661, 18661, 18661, 18661, 18661, 18661, 18661, 18661, 
18661, 18661, 18661, 18661, 18661, 18662, 18662, 18662, 18662, 
18662, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18663, 18667, 18667, 18667, 
18669, 18669, 18669, 18669, 18669, 18669, 18669, 18669, 18675, 
18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18675, 18683, 18683, 18683, 
18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 
18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 18683, 18687, 
18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 
18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 18689, 
18689, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 
18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 
18690, 18690, 18690, 18690, 18691, 18691, 18691, 18691, 18694, 
18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 
18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 
18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18694, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 
18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 
18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 
18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18695, 18697, 
18697, 18697, 18697, 18697, 18697, 18697, 18697, 18697, 18697, 
18697, 18701, 18702, 18702, 18702, 18702, 18702, 18702, 18702, 
18703, 18703, 18703, 18703, 18703, 18718, 18744, 18744, 18749, 
18749, 18751, 18751, 18753, 18753, 18753, 18753, 18753, 18754, 
18755, 18755, 18756, 18756, 18756, 18757, 18757, 18757, 18757, 
18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 18758, 18759, 
18759, 18759, 18759, 18759, 18759, 18760, 18760, 18760, 18760, 
18760, 18760, 18760, 18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 
18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 
18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 18761, 18762, 18762, 18762, 18762, 
18762, 18762, 18762, 18762, 18762, 18762, 18762, 18763, 18763, 
18763, 18763, 18763, 18763, 18763, 18763, 18763, 18763, 18763, 
18763, 18763, 18763, 18763, 18763, 18763, 18764, 18764, 18764, 
18764, 18764, 18764, 18764, 18764, 18764, 18765, 18765, 18765, 
18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 
18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 
18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18765, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 
18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 
18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 18766, 
18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 
18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 
18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18767, 18768, 18768, 18768, 18768, 
18768, 18768, 18768, 18768, 18768, 18768, 18768, 18768, 18768, 
18768, 18768, 18768, 18768, 18768, 18768, 18769, 18769, 18769, 
18769, 18769, 18769, 18769, 18769, 18769, 18769, 18769, 18769, 
18769), class = "Date"), ID = c("afh2745", "afh2790", "afh2791", 
"afh2796", "afh2798", "afh2800", "avl3251", "avl5042", "avl6835", 
"avl7197", "afh2764", "afh2769", "avl6837", "avl6838", "avl7042", 
"avl7173", "avl7174", "avl5520", "avl5521", "avl6844", "avl6845", 
"avl6846", "avl6847", "avl6849", "avl6850", "avl6851", "avl6852", 
"avl6854", "avl6855", "avl6856", "avl6857", "avl6860", "avl7464", 
"avl7472", "avl3578", "avl4902", "avl6399", "avl6835", "avl6862", 
"avl6863", "avl6864", "avl6866", "avl6871", "avl6872", "avl7149", 
"avl4018", "avl4045", "avl4211", "avl4221", "avl4250", "avl4269", 
"avl4308", "avl4422", "avl6246", "avl6367", "avl6400", "avl6874", 
"avl6876", "avl6879", "avl6880", "avl6881", "avl6882", "avl6883", 
"avl6884", "avl6885", "avl6888", "avl6889", "avl6890", "avl6891", 
"avl6892", "avl6894", "avl6895", "avl6896", "avl6897", "avl6898", 
"avl7164", "avl3545", "avl3578", "avl3596", "avl3691", "avl4398", 
"avl4904", "avl4911", "avl4912", "avl4913", "avl4915", "avl6029", 
"avl7481", "avl4148", "avl4228", "avl4328", "avl4917", "avl4918", 
"avl4919", "avl4920", "avl4922", "avl4925", "avl4926", "avl4927", 
"avl4929", "avl4930", "avl4931", "avl4932", "avl4933", "avl4934", 
"avl5183", "avl6247", "avl6316", "avl6385", "avl6490", "avl7170", 
"afh2742", "afh2743", "afh2791", "afh2798", "avl6835", "avl6894", 
"avl7197", "avl7873", "avl7874", "avl7875", "avl7876", "avl7877", 
"avl7878", "avl7880", "d182385", "avl3084", "avl6191", "avl7881", 
"avl7882", "avl7884", "afh2789", "afh2791", "avl3138", "avl7885", 
"avl7886", "afh2742", "afh2790", "d182385", "afh2781", "avl6170", 
"avl6176", "avl6183", "avl6193", "avl6194", "avl7884", "avl7887", 
"avl4513", "avl6364", "avl7146", "avl7150", "avl7890", "avl7892", 
"avl7894", "abj6404", "abj6405", "abj6406", "abj6407", "abj6409", 
"avl3751", "avl4010", "avl4218", "avl4237", "avl4315", "avl4422", 
"avl6331", "avl6332", "avl6367", "avl6876", "avl6883", "avl6884", 
"avl6889", "avl6890", "avl7898", "avl6193", "abj6411", "abj6412", 
"abj6413", "abj6414", "abj6415", "abj6417", "abj6418", "abj6419", 
"abj6420", "abj6421", "afh2751", "avl3089", "avl3255", "avl3552", 
"avl4295", "avl5628", "avl6159", "avl6162", "avl7199", "abj6423", 
"abj6424", "abj6428", "abj6429", "abj6431", "abj6432", "abj6433", 
"abj6435", "abj6442", "abj6443", "abj6444", "abj6448", "abj6451", 
"avl3510", "avl3658", "avl3708", "avl3746", "avl3818", "avl3978", 
"avl6209", "avl7515", "avl3768", "avl3907", "avl4724", "avl7150", 
"abj6453", "abj6454", "abj6455", "abj6456", "abj6457", "abj6458", 
"abj6461", "abj6463", "abj6465", "abj6471", "afh2882", "avl3932", 
"avl4126", "avl4174", "avl4641", "avl4918", "avl4920", "avl6032", 
"avl6247", "avl6400", "avl6490", "avl6866", "avl7596", "avl7877", 
"abj6473", "abj6474", "abj6475", "abj6476", "abj6477", "abj6479", 
"abj6481", "abj6482", "abj6485", "abj6487", "abj6490", "abj6491", 
"abj6496", "abj6497", "abj6498", "abj6499", "avl3697", "avl4141", 
"avl4328", "avl4397", "avl4550", "avl5436", "avl5439", "avl5440", 
"avl5442", "avl5906", "avl6622", "avl6864", "avl7139", "avl7884", 
"avl4328", "avl5445", "avl5446", "avl5450", "avl5451", "avl5452", 
"avl5454", "avl5455", "avl5456", "avl5457", "avl7210", "avl5458", 
"avl4018", "avl4221", "avl4250", "avl4280", "avl5459", "avl5461", 
"avl6891", "avl3987", "avl4100", "avl5464", "avl5466", "avl5468", 
"afh2847", "avl3744", "avl4297", "afh2864", "avl5520", "avl5098", 
"avl5563", "abj6413", "abj6415", "abj6498", "avl4141", "avl6851", 
"avl7474", "afh2777", "avl3509", "avl3064", "avl4295", "avl6385", 
"avl3978", "avl4018", "avl5520", "avl5596", "atr5701", "avl3882", 
"avl4272", "avl4297", "avl4549", "avl5459", "avl5461", "avl6194", 
"afh2888", "atr5702", "avl4511", "avl5466", "avl6132", "avl6864", 
"afh5509", "atr5703", "avl3596", "avl5442", "avl6851", "avl7450", 
"avl7515", "afh2887", "atr4202", "atr4203", "atr5201", "avl3509", 
"avl3818", "avl4100", "avl4211", "avl4280", "avl4297", "avl4931", 
"avl5456", "avl5803", "avl6247", "avl6396", "avl6892", "avl7115", 
"avl7139", "avl7188", "avl7494", "abj6407", "abj6455", "afh2888", 
"atr7201", "avl3691", "avl4010", "avl4269", "avl4902", "avl6132", 
"avl6890", "avl7455", "afh2866", "atr4204", "atr4206", "atr4217", 
"atr7202", "atr7203", "avl3556", "avl3575", "avl4142", "avl4208", 
"avl5461", "avl5906", "avl6662", "avl6890", "avl7497", "avl7875", 
"avl7877", "afh2754", "avl3084", "avl3978", "avl4308", "avl4612", 
"avl4656", "avl5466", "avl5826", "avl6132", "afh2769", "afh2866", 
"afh4277", "atr4229", "atr4715", "atr4716", "atr5764", "atr5765", 
"atr5766", "avl3596", "avl3692", "avl4174", "avl4280", "avl4930", 
"avl4932", "avl6042", "avl6086", "avl6121", "avl6136", "avl6209", 
"avl6894", "avl6898", "avl7188", "avl7403", "avl7467", "avl7472", 
"abj6411", "abj6457", "afh2755", "atr4248", "atr4260", "atr4721", 
"atr4722", "atr5784", "atr6701", "avl4100", "avl4153", "avl4269", 
"avl4318", "avl5138", "avl5442", "avl5701", "avl5803", "avl5906", 
"avl6396", "avl6864", "avl7188", "avl7882", "abj6407", "abj6461", 
"afh2751", "atr4318", "atr4741", "atr5807", "atr5808", "atr6713", 
"avl3691", "avl3711", "avl4031", "avl4191", "avl4523", "avl4913", 
"avl5060", "avl6170", "avl6315", "avl6890", "avl7185", "avl7818", 
"avl7875", "avl7884", "j215781", "abj6421", "abj6498", "atr5261", 
"atr5865", "atr6212", "atr6723", "atr7224", "atr7225", "avl3575", 
"avl4141", "avl4173", "avl4549", "avl5098", "avl5464", "avl5596", 
"avl6702", "avl6703", "avl6849", "avl7213", "afh2754", "afh2772", 
"afh2777", "afh2779", "afh2781", "afh2864", "afh2869", "atr4339", 
"atr4760", "atr5268", "atr5874", "atr5876", "atr5877"), n = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), cumcount = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
15L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -500L), groups = structure(list(
    Date = structure(c(18632, 18633, 18642, 18649, 18654, 18655, 
    18656, 18661, 18662, 18663, 18667, 18669, 18675, 18683, 18687, 
    18689, 18690, 18691, 18694, 18695, 18697, 18701, 18702, 18703, 
    18718, 18744, 18749, 18751, 18753, 18754, 18755, 18756, 18757, 
    18758, 18759, 18760, 18761, 18762, 18763, 18764, 18765, 18766, 
    18767, 18768, 18769), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:10, 11:17, 18:34, 35:45, 46:76, 77:88, 89:111, 112:126, 
        127:131, 132:136, 137:139, 140:147, 148:154, 155:174, 
        175L, 176:194, 195:215, 216:219, 220:243, 244:273, 274:284, 
        285L, 286:292, 293:297, 298L, 299:300, 301:302, 303:304, 
        305:309, 310L, 311:312, 313:315, 316:319, 320:327, 328:333, 
        334:340, 341:360, 361:371, 372:388, 389:397, 398:423, 
        424:445, 446:468, 469:487, 488:500), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -45L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Just for ease of understanding here is what the data look like in table format

```
 Date       ID     n cumcount
   <date>     <chr>    <int>    <int>
 1 2021-01-05 afh2745      1        1
 2 2021-01-05 afh2790      1        2
 3 2021-01-05 afh2791      1        3
 4 2021-01-05 afh2796      1        4
 5 2021-01-05 afh2798      1        5
 6 2021-01-05 afh2800      1        6
 7 2021-01-05 avl3251      1        7
 8 2021-01-05 avl5042      1        8
 9 2021-01-05 avl6835      1        9
10 2021-01-05 avl7197      1       10
11 2021-01-06 afh2764      1        1
12 2021-01-06 afh2769      1        2
13 2021-01-06 avl6837      1        3
14 2021-01-06 avl6838      1        4
15 2021-01-06 avl7042      1        5
16 2021-01-06 avl7173      1        6
17 2021-01-06 avl7174      1        7
18 2021-01-15 avl5520      1        1
19 2021-01-15 avl5521      1        2
20 2021-01-15 avl6844      1        3
21 2021-01-15 avl6845      1        4
22 2021-01-15 avl6846      1        5
23 2021-01-15 avl6847      1        6
24 2021-01-15 avl6849      1        7
25 2021-01-15 avl6850      1        8
```

What I would like to do next is get the overall cumulative totals day by day.
I have tried the following

```
df %>%
  mutate(max_count = max(cumcount)) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  count(Date) %>%
  mutate(new_cumcount = cumsum(n))
```

However this is the result I get

```
Date           n new_cumcount
   <date>     <int>        <int>
 1 2021-01-05    10           10
 2 2021-01-06     7            7
 3 2021-01-15    17           17
 4 2021-01-22    11           11
 5 2021-01-27    31           31
 6 2021-01-28    12           12
 7 2021-01-29    23           23
 8 2021-02-03    15           15
 9 2021-02-04     5            5
10 2021-02-05     5            5
```

Why does the newly created col using `mutate` just repeat the col that I am trying use `cumsum` on. What am I missing?
For absolute clarity, I wish to have one days total added to the next and so on for all of the dates.

Comment: The result you get is the aggregated data you asked for.

Comment: Perhaps I need to edit to make it clearer that I wish to have the previous days totals added to the next day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could summarize the data with the maximum of `max_count` for each `Date` and calculate the cumulative sums for those maxima.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(max_count = max(cumcount)) %>%
  # summarise() automatically drops the last level of grouping, i.e. Date
  mutate(new_cumcount = cumsum(max_count))

# # A tibble: 45 × 3
#    Date       max_count new_cumcount
#    <date>         <int>        <int>
#  1 2021-01-05        10           10
#  2 2021-01-06         7           17
#  3 2021-01-15        17           34
#  4 2021-01-22        11           45
#  5 2021-01-27        31           76
#  6 2021-01-28        12           88
#  7 2021-01-29        23          111
#  8 2021-02-03        15          126
#  9 2021-02-04         5          131
# 10 2021-02-05         5          136
# # … with 35 more rows
```

Comment: Excellent, but I still don't understand why ```cumsum``` doesn't work like it should on the original set of data?

Comment: The last `cumsum` should be evaluated without grouping. Hence, with your code, you should insert `%>% ungroup()` before `mutate(new_cumcount = cumsum(n))`.